# mysql: command not found, on Amazon AWS Lightsail terminal

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I encountered and spend around an hour on this issue. 
 While following the documentation on https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/get-started/connect-mysql/ in order to change the admin user email address, on Amazon AWS browser-based SSH client Lightsail terminal, when executing

```
mysql -u root -p
```

it returns `-bash: mysqld: command not found`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is to create an alias of command to locate the working mysql path. In my case, mysql path is path is `/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysql`. Therefore, I created an alias to that path by:

- first, `sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc`,
- second, add this line : `alias mysql='sudo /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysql'`, save it.
- third, exit the terminal, and start the terminal again.
- From now, I can execute `mysql` command as usual and continue following the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: locate whete is the correct path with this command:

```
sudo find / -name mysql
```

Step 2:  Several results will probably appear for mysql, the correct is the one that contains the word 'bin'.

In my casem in Bitnami LAMP 2023 image on AWS, the path is:

```
/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysql
```

Then, yoy can call mysql by prepending the path and the habitual parameters:

```
/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

It should works.